# InteractionRequestTrigger PopupWindowAction custom icon

Tags: wpf, prism

I am using PRISM 5 and I am showing a custom view using a `InteractionRequestTrigger` and `PopupWindowAction`. 
Does anybody have an idea on how to set the icon of the dialog window?

Answer (score 3):

**Note: This works only for Prism 6 and above**

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding SomeInteractionRequest, Mode=OneWay}" >
        <prism:PopupWindowAction>
            <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="Window">
                    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="put here your icon"/>
                </Style>
            </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowStyle>
            <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                <!-- put your own view here -->
                <local:SettingsWindowView />
            </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
        </prism:PopupWindowAction>
    </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

where namespaces

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
```

and there is no need to create a child class from `PopupWindowAction`

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer myself, the solution is (I think) in deriving a class from **PopupWindowAction** that has a new Icon `DependencyProperty`. I also added an assertion to check whether the notification.Title is null or empty, in that case I set the wrapperWindow.Title to the empty string.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity;
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity.InteractionRequest;

/// <summary>
/// Shows a popup window with in response to an <see cref="InteractionRequest"/> being raised.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// This popup window has an Icon property that can be used to set the icon
/// </remarks>
public class IconPopupWindowAction : PopupWindowAction
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The icon of the child window that is displayed as part of the popup.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Icon",
        typeof(ImageSource),
        typeof(IconPopupWindowAction),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Icon of the window.
    /// </summary>
    public ImageSource Icon
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)this.GetValue(IconProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the window to display as part of the trigger action.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="notification">The notification to be set as a DataContext in the window.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The popup window
    /// </returns>
    protected override Window GetWindow(INotification notification)
    {
        Window wrapperWindow;

        if (this.WindowContent != null)
        {
            wrapperWindow = new Window();

            // If the WindowContent does not have its own DataContext, it will inherit this one.
            wrapperWindow.DataContext = notification;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(notification.Title))
            {
                wrapperWindow.Title = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                wrapperWindow.Title = notification.Title;
            }

            wrapperWindow.Icon = this.Icon;

            this.PrepareContentForWindow(notification, wrapperWindow);
        }
        else
        {
            wrapperWindow = this.CreateDefaultWindow(notification);
            wrapperWindow.Icon = this.Icon;
        }

        return wrapperWindow;
    }
}
```

Comment: simplify `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(notification.Title)) { wrapperWindow.Title string.Empty; } else { wrapperWindow.Title = notification.Title; }` with only `wrapperWindow.Title = notification.Title;` they are the same

Comment: This solution has a downside, you are overriding a method which is implemented by Prism Library, as Prism Library could released with a newer version, this class will not using the new code of the prism. See my solution to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

A very simpler solution could be

```
public class IconPopupWindowAction : PopupWindowAction
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(IconPopupWindowAction), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public ImageSource Icon
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)this.GetValue(IconProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override Window GetWindow(INotification notification)
    {
        Window defaultWindow = base.GetWindow(notification);
        defaultWindow.Icon = this.Icon;
        return defaultWindow;
    }
}
```

**This is also Better** because the solution you provided is a copy and paste from the [Prism implementation of this method](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Interactivity/PopupWindowAction.cs#L224), but you modified it a little. 
Unfortunately, The implementation of the prism could be changed _ *and actually, it really changed, from the time you copied it* _ 
 
So with your way you have to update your `IconPopupWindowAction` class to keep sync with Prism.
This solution is **Better** because instead of copying the code from the Prism library, it *really reuse it* by calling the base method `base.GetWindow(notification)`. 
This protects you from breaking the Prism code when you update the Prism, to a newer version.

Answer (score -1):

Go the project properties (select the project from the solution explorer and click <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

From the **Application** tab go the **Icon and manifest** and select the icon for your project, this will set the icon to every window in the project.
And there is NO any need for `IconPopupWindowAction` class